# Server Time Problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I've got a little script I'm working on which saves a comment to a mysql database, the database having a field of type "timestamp" and default set to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

On the client side, I'm using the timeago jquery plugin (http://timeago.yarp.com/) wihch takes a UTC timestamp and converts it to a relative time format like "5 minutes ago"

However, my server time is set in a different time zone.  This means that, if I'm posting a comment at 4 o'clock, the timestamp being put in the timestamp field is that of the server time, which is behind my local time.  Thus when I'm posting a comment which is only a few minutes old, the jquery timeago plugin is showing something like "four hours ago"

How do I solve this problem.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

All your timestamps should be in UTC, regardless of your server's local time.  It's probably being converted somewhere along the way... e.g. as you're retrieving it.

I have all my timestamps stored as unixtime (unsigned integers) and convert them when they need to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UTC_TIMESTAMP` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp

Comment: but how to I include this in my query, which is like this:  SELECT * FROM threaded_comments WHERE parent_id = 0 order by created_at DESC

Comment: first, I would update all your comment times to UTC using `CONVERT_TZ` (search for it on the above link). Then change your default comment setting to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP`. Then change any code that you supply a comment timestamp explicitly to use a UTC timestamp. Then your SELECT query will "just work"™

Comment: if you don't want to go through the 'trouble' of keeping your comments uniform, you can add CONVERT_TZ(commentTime, 'current tz', '+00:00') to your select query and use that value instead of the default commentTime

Answer (score 0):

You must tell mysql to not be dependant on the timezone of your server.
One way to do that is to execute the following command :

```
mysql> SET time_zone = '+00:00';
```

this way, your requests with time will all be on the UTC timezone.

check this [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) for further explanations.

your problem comes from the fact that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gives you the timestamp of the current timezone of the mysql server. If not set, the timezone of the mysql server inherits the timezone of the server.